# In iOS, how can I detect if a cell in UITableview is in the process of being swiped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I'm using `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to detect and process swipes. However, I need to be able to detect when the user started to swipe, but before it completes. The problem is that if I update the table using `reloadData()` or `beginUpdates()` / `endUpdates()` while a cell is being swiped, it resets the cell to the un-swiped position (and I don't like that kind of  user experience). I want to be able to delay the cell/data update until the swipe is finished or cancelled.

Comment: You could implement `willTransition(to:)` in the `UITableViewCell` to detect a swipe:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623240-willtransition

Comment: That will work. I'll need to keep track of the state of any cell that transitions out of the default state, but it'll definitely let me do what I need. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as being correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though Andreas' answer is absolutely correct, I found an easier way to do it. Apparently, whenever `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` is used, the cell is marked as being edited whenever it starts being swiped. And that allows us to use `willBeginEditingRowAt` and `didEndEditingRowAt` on the `UITableView`, without having to worry about the `UITableViewCell`

```
var swipedRow: IndexPath? = nil
        
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    swipedRow = indexPath
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    swipedRow = nil
}
```

And then you can just check if `swipedRow  == nil` (plus, if it's not `nil`, you will know the indexPath of the row being swiped)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `willTransition(to:) in the` UITableViewCell` to detect a swipe, see:
[UITableViewCell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623240-willtransition)

There, just set a flag in the view controller to prevent updates.
You might also need to do something in `viewWillDisappear` or so, because maybe the transition callbacks are not called under some circumstances.